# How to use FieldValue.serverTimestamp() in POJO/Model for status timestamps?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pojo

I have an order collection. A user can request and cancel the order and receive the order.

There were three statuses here:
 - Requested Order
 - Canceled Order
 - Received Order

I will explain the question with codes. as follows:

Order Model Class:

```
public class Order {
    private String userId;
    private String productId;
    @OrderStatus
    private int status;
    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date requestedAt;
    private Date canceledAt;
    private Date receivedAt;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Date getRequestedAt() {
        return requestedAt;
    }

    public void setRequestedAt(Date requestedAt) {
        this.requestedAt = requestedAt;
    }

    public Date getCanceledAt() {
        return canceledAt;
    }

    public void setCanceledAt(Date canceledAt) {
        this.canceledAt = canceledAt;
    }

    public Date getReceivedAt() {
        return receivedAt;
    }

    public void setReceivedAt(Date receivedAt) {
        this.receivedAt = receivedAt;
    }
}
```

Status Enum:

```
public @interface OrderStatus {
    int OS_REQUESTED = 0;
    int OS_USER_CANCELED = 1;
    int OS_RECEIVED = 2;
}
```

when the user requests an order:

```
public static void requestOrder(String userId, String productId) {
    Order order = new Order();
    order.setUserId(userId);
    order.setProductId(productId);
    order.setStatus(OrderStatus.OS_REQUESTED);

    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("orders")
        .add(order);
}
```

Up to now, the requestedDate has been successfully filled with the server timestamp.

But when the user cancels the order:

```
public static void cancelOrder(String orderId, @NonNull Order order) {
    order.setStatus(OrderStatus.OS_CANCELED);
    order.setCanceledAt(new Date()); // how to use FieldValue.serverTimestamp() here?

    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("orders")
        .document(orderId)
        .set(order);
}
```

Of course I can do it using Update. in that:

```
public static void cancelOrder(String orderId) {
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("status", OrderStatus.OS_CANCELED);
    data.put("canceledAt", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("orders")
        .document(orderId)
        .update(data);
}
```

But I want to use POJO/Model.

- **If** i add @ServerTimetamp annotation to the CancelledAt property **then** it will be filled in when the order is requested. So:

```
public class Order {
    ...

    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date requestedAt;

    @ServerTimestamp // <-- will be filled in the order request if added
    private Date canceledAt;

    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date receivedAt;

    ...
}
```

- If I change its type to Timestamp, how do I assign FieldValue.serverTimestamp()?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a server timestamp as the value of a POJO property, you will need to use the [@ServerTimetamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/ServerTimestamp) annotation. I believe the value should be of [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) type.

Comment: I updated my question. please look again. Do you think @Servertimestamp annotation should be added for "canceledDate"? Or how do I assign FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to my variable of Timestamp type?

Comment: Put the annotation on the getter for the method, not the private field.

Comment: Your answer is not about the question I asked. Thanks anyway.